# SQL insert avoiding duplicates from queried table + avoiding to insert duplicates in updated table

Tags: mysql, duplicates

I wish to update specific columns of a table from certain columns from a second table avoiding duplicates in a unique column, with the extra twist that the second table itself has duplicates.

```
INSERT INTO cie (cik,name,sic,fye)
SELECT dumpsubq2.cik,dumpsubq2.name,dumpsubq2.sic,dumpsubq2.fye
 FROM dumpsubq2
 WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT cik
                   FROM cie 
                   WHERE dumpsubq2.cik = cie.cik)
```

Now this would work fine if only there were no duplicates in the dumpsubq2 Table. So the exploit is to somehow include **DISTINCT** while querying the dumpsubq2 table. And i fail to achieve this in one pass :/

Do i have to do this in 2 steps ?

1. Eliminating duplicates in the dumpsubq2 in a temp table
2. Play above query that stops with (error #1062 - Duplicate entry '1606069' for key 'cie.cik') when it encounters a duplicate in dumpsubq2)

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: *I wish to update...* but your query is not an UPDATE statement. Clarify what you want.

Comment: The simple solution would be to use `INSERT IGNORE`, but I think you should provide some more information. We don't know if your rows in `dumpsubq2` are complete duplicates (as in, all columns are exactly the same) or only the `cik` column. And if so, which value should be inserted for the other columns?

Comment: Pepper, Thank you for your reply :) The rows in dumpsubq2 are not complete duplicates. The dumpsubq2 tables has many columns, none are unique (uniqueness needs compounding 2 fields). Some cik have duplicates, not all. I only need the 4 (cik,name,sic,fye).  Won't **INSERT IGNORE** generate doubles in my cie table ?

Comment: Hello forpas. Sorry i missused UPDATE. I used UPDATE because my request ADDS data to an existing table that already has data filling it's rows. Some -not all- of that existing data has duplicates in the queried table AND there are some duplicates within that queried table. I think should follow the an intermediary #temp table solution. I realize this exploit is quite a challenge. Thank you for your replying :)

Comment: Hello this solution did it for me '''INSERT INTO cie(cik,name,sic,fye)
SELECT * from ( select distinct cik,name,sic,fye FROM `dumpsubq2` WHERE form = '10-k') AS tmp
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT cik FROM cie WHERE tmp.cik = cie.cik
)
'''

Answer (score 0):

This query did it for me :)

```
INSERT INTO cie(cik,name,sic,fye)
SELECT * from ( select distinct cik,name,sic,fye FROM `dumpsubq2` WHERE form = '10-k') AS tmp
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT cik FROM cie WHERE tmp.cik = cie.cik
)
```